# Performance and memory problems in rust async program

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future, rust-tokio

I wanted to benchmark requests from rust to particular service using async client, and created async benchmarker for that.

This function should run specified amount of concurrent threads (actually, parallel chains of futures) for specified duration and report count of iterations achieved.

```rust
use futures::future;
use futures::prelude::*;
use std::error::Error;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use std::{cell, io, rc};
use tokio::runtime::current_thread::Runtime;
use tokio::timer;

struct Config {
    workers: u32,
    duration: Duration,
}

/// Build infinitely repeating future
fn cycle<'a, F: Fn() -> P + 'a, P: Future + 'a>(
    f: F,
) -> Box<dyn Future<Item = (), Error = P::Error> + 'a> {
    Box::new(f().and_then(move |_| cycle(f)))
}

fn benchmark<'a, F: Fn() -> P + 'a, P: Future<Error = io::Error> + 'a>(
    config: Config,
    f: F,
) -> impl Future<Item = u32, Error = io::Error> + 'a {
    let counter = rc::Rc::new(cell::Cell::new(0u32));
    let f = rc::Rc::new(f);
    future::select_all((0..config.workers).map({
        let counter = rc::Rc::clone(&counter);
        move |_| {
            let counter = rc::Rc::clone(&counter);
            let f = rc::Rc::clone(&f);
            cycle(move || {
                let counter = rc::Rc::clone(&counter);
                f().map(move |_| {
                    counter.set(counter.get() + 1);
                })
            })
        }
    }))
    .map(|((), _, _)| ())
    .map_err(|(err, _, _)| err)
    .select(
        timer::Delay::new(Instant::now() + config.duration)
            .map_err(|err| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, err.description())),
    )
    .map(move |((), _)| counter.get())
    .map_err(|(err, _)| err)
}

fn main() {
    let duration = std::env::args()
        .skip(1)
        .next()
        .expect("Please provide duration in seconds")
        .parse()
        .expect("Duration must be integer number");

    let ms = Duration::from_millis(1);

    let mut rt = Runtime::new().expect("Could not create runtime");

    loop {
        let iters = rt
            .block_on(
                benchmark(
                    Config {
                        workers: 65536,
                        duration: Duration::from_secs(duration),
                    },
                    || {
                        /// Substitute actual benchmarked call
                        timer::Delay::new(Instant::now() + ms)
                            .map_err(|err| panic!("Failed to set delay: {:?}", err))
                    },
                )
                .map_err(|err| panic!("Benchamrking error: {:?}", err)),
            )
            .expect("Runtime error");
        println!("{} iters/sec", iters as u64 / duration);
    }
}
```

However, the result this benchmark reports and memory consumption degrades with increase of benchmark duration, e.g. on my pc:

`cargo run --release 1` ~ 900k iterations/sec
`cargo run --release 2` ~ 700k iterations/sec
`cargo run --release 10` ~ 330k iterations/sec

Also, memory usage rapidly grows as benchmark function runs. I tried using `valgrind` to find memory leak but it only reports that all allocated memory can still be reached.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: I didn't understand a thing in your benchmark func but why do you get the result with `iters as u64 / duration` that just don't make sense to me

Comment: @Stargateur Iters is total iterations over duration, and I wanted iterations per second.

Comment: I think the `Box` returned by `cycle` is not freed until the end of `future::select_all`, and that would explain the increasing memory consumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out `cycle` really was a culprit [as Gregory suspected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56991161/2195721). I found this useful function in futures crate: [loop_fn](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.28/futures/future/fn.loop_fn.html), and rewritten `cycle` using it:

```rust
/// Build infinitely repeating future
fn cycle<'a, F: Fn() -> P + 'a, P: Future + 'a>(
    f: F,
) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = P::Error> + 'a {
    future::loop_fn((), move |_| f().map(|_| future::Loop::Continue(())))
}
```

The rest of the code remains the same. Now this compiles with stable rust and even reports almost twice as much iterations per second as proposed nightly futures solution (for what it's worth with this synthetic test).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the `Box` returned by `cycle` is not freed until the end of `benchmark`, and the memory allocation / deallocation take more and more time.

I have rewritten your program with `async_await`, without the `Box` and the results are now consistent :

```rust
#![feature(async_await)]

use futures::{compat::Future01CompatExt, future, prelude::*, select};
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use tokio::timer;

struct Config {
    workers: u32,
    duration: Duration,
}

// Build infinitely repeating future
async fn cycle<'a, F: Fn() -> P + 'a, P: Future<Output = ()> + 'a>(f: F) {
    loop {
        f().await;
    }
}

async fn benchmark<'a, F: Fn() -> P + 'a, P: Future<Output = ()> + 'a>(
    config: Config,
    f: F,
) -> usize {
    let counter = AtomicUsize::new(0);

    let infinite_counter = future::select_all((0..config.workers).map(|_| {
        cycle(|| {
            f().map(|_| {
                counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
            })
        })
        .boxed_local()
    }));

    let timer = timer::Delay::new(Instant::now() + config.duration)
        .compat()
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Boom !"));

    select! {
        a = infinite_counter.fuse() => (),
        b = timer.fuse() => (),
    };

    counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst)
}

fn main() {
    let duration = std::env::args()
        .skip(1)
        .next()
        .expect("Please provide duration in seconds")
        .parse()
        .expect("Duration must be integer number");

    let ms = Duration::from_millis(1);

    // Use actix_rt runtime instead of vanilla tokio because I want
    // to restrict to one OS thread and avoid needing async primitives
    let mut rt = actix_rt::Runtime::new().expect("Could not create runtime");;

    loop {
        let iters = rt
            .block_on(
                benchmark(
                    Config {
                        workers: 65536,
                        duration: Duration::from_secs(duration),
                    },
                    || {
                        // Substitute actual benchmarked call
                        timer::Delay::new(Instant::now() + ms)
                            .compat()
                            .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Boom !"))
                    },
                )
                .boxed_local()
                .unit_error()
                .compat(),
            )
            .expect("Runtime error");
        println!("{} iters/sec", iters as u64 / duration);
    }
}
```

It's my first time with futures 0.3, so I don't really get some parts like the `select!` syntax, or the `boxed_local`, but it works !

---

EDIT: Here is the dependencies block from `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
futures-preview = { version = "0.3.0-alpha", features = ["nightly", "compat", "async-await"] }
tokio = "0.1.22"
actix-rt = "0.2.3"
```

Comment: Can confirm this code seems to work without leaks, thanks! Hopefully sooner or later I will find a way to make it work with stable rust, but at least I have some solution for the meantime.

Comment: Actually, the code I wanted to benchmark implements 0.1 Futures and will not work with this benchmark definition :( `the trait core::future::future::Future is not implemented for impl futures::future::Future`)

Comment: You can use future compatibility, with the `compat` method, provided by `futures::compat::Future01CompatExt`, and by `TryFuture` (or something like that), a future with a result output.